# loopback - authorize GET Users?

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a project with loopback using postgres and, by default I am not authorized to GET Users (error 401). I don't have a user.json and user.js on my common/models.
How do I do to change the acl of the User model?
After some researches I think I understood that some people recreate a user.json and then migrate it? Is it the way to overwrite the acl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user ACL (and most acls) work on a DENY *, and add exceptions for what is necessary.  If you don't want to extend the default model you can use.

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);

    // Allow GET Users
    const User = app.models.User;
    User.settings.acls.push(
      {
        'principalType': 'ROLE',
        'property': 'find',
        'principalId': '$everyone',
        'permission': 'ALLOW'
      }
    );


    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

Comment: It didn't change anything sadly

Comment: Did you put it in a boot script or in `server.js`?  I'm using it on a blank loopback project right now and it's working.

Comment: Oh, I put it in a file and the executed it, thinking it would permanently overwrite it. Now that I have it in server.js it works. Thank you so much!!